# How to make a directive that adds a class "show" bootstrap 4 class to to an unordered list(which is not visible), on click of a link?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have been given an assignment where I have to open a bootstrap 4 drop down menu on click ,by making a directive that will add a show class to the unordered list when the dropdown is clicked (bootstrap javascript cdn is not allowed)

I made a directive named 'appDropdown', it binds the class 'show' to a boolean variable named 'isOpen',I then listen for a click and then toggle the 'isOpen' variable,hence whenever I click the class 'show' gets added or removed at the element where the directive is placed.

HTML code

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" appDropdown>    <!--this is where i need a class 'show' to be added when the above button is clicked !-->
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Add Ingredients to Shopping Lists</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Edit recipe</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Delete recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code

```
import {Directive, HostListener, HostBinding,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector:'[appDropdown]'
})

export class appDropdown implements  {


 @HostBinding('class.show') isOpen:boolean=false;
 @HostListener('click',['$event.target']) toggleOpen(target){
    this.isOpen=!this.isOpen;
    console.log(this.isOpen);
    console.log(target)
}
```

It was expected that class show gets added or removed on toggle of the dropdown button,but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exportAs` meta property in directive to achieve what you want:

first of all, define a directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostBinding, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropdown]",
  exportAs: "myDir"
})
export class DropDownDirective {
  public isShow = false;

  @HostBinding("class.show") get opened() {
    return this.isShow;
  }

  @HostListener("click") open() {
    this.isShow = !this.isShow;
  }
}
```

then in your component define a `ViewChild` to access the button:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("temp", { static: true }) vc: DropDownDirective;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.vc.isShow);
  }
}
```

and finally in your html :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button #temp=myDir appDropdown type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" [class.show]="this.vc.isShow">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Add Ingredients to Shopping Lists</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Edit recipe</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Delete recipe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3sznr)

Comment: Hey AbolfazIR thanks for the solution ,but I was looking to make a directive which is generic so i don't have to use the components typescript file, is there any way to make it happen?